# Rails 3.0 Sending Email Security Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

What security concerns do I need to take into account for sending email for a contact form?

I know in php one must be careful about constructing email headers because depending on what is injected into a contact form they can use that to send spam out to other people using your email server.

Do I need to take this into account for sending mail in Rails 3.0 with ActionMailer? Or does it handle most of it for me?

Are there any other security concerns I should worry about when writing basic emailing things like contact forms?

Sorry if the questions seem silly, I'm starting out with rails and really love it so far, but sometimes I'm not sure what the best practices are for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you've described that could happen in PHP shouldn't come up normally in Rails.

That would only be possible if you're setting the recipient on your Mailer dynamically. When sending an email from Rails, specify the recipient/s for your contact form in your Mailer explicitly. If your email is sending html and you're allowing html in your form, make sure you escape any input in the template for your email.